# Characterization of the inverse of a diagonally dominant symmetric M-matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, m-matrix

I was looking for a proof or counter-example for a hypothesis that states that the inverse of a nonsingular nonnegative symmetric diagonally dominant matrix with the same value on the diagonal is a diagonally dominant M-matrix.  I believe this is evident when the matrix is $2\times2$ and i wasn't able to find a counter-example using numerical experiments.

I found this [article](http://repositorio.uchile.cl/bitstream/handle/2250/174923/Inverse-M-matrix.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y) on the characterization of inverse M-matrices that states the following definition and theorem (which i'm paraphrasing)

> A nonnegative, nonsingular matrix $U$ is called a *potential* if its inverse
> $M = U^{−1}$ is a row diagonally dominant M-matrix ...

and

> If $U$ is a nonnegative nonsingular symmetric matrix, then $U$ is a potential
> iff it satisfies $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n \;\,\langle(Ux − \mathbf{1})
> ^+, x\rangle ≥ 0 $

or equivalently

> if $ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ it holds: $$\sup_i (Ux)_i\leq \sup_{i\text{ s.t. } x_i≥0}(Ux)_i$$
> This says that if $x$ has at least one nonnegative coordinate then the maximum
> value among the coordinates of $y = Ux$ is attained at some coordinate $i$ such that $x_i$ is nonnegative.

I was wondering if a nonsingular nonnegative symmetric diagonally dominant matrix with a constant diagonal is a  potential matrix. And if not I am looking for either a proof or a counterexample for the hypothesis.